# Rename multiple files by name Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to vba and I need a excel macro that depending on the file name, assigns it another name, for example:

```
aaa12345.txt -----> hello.txt
bb678.txt -----> bye.txt
```

there are only two types of names in the folder, aaa*.txt and bb*.txt

```
Sub rena_me()
if ffile = Dir("C:\test\aaa*.txt") Then NewName = "yellow.txt"
Name "C:\test\" & ffile As "c:\test\" & NewName
End sub
```

this code is all I have got... works fine, but I don't know how to implement it for both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following macro...

```
Option Explicit

Sub rena_me()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim newName As String

    myPath = "C:\test\"

    'check for an aaa file
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "aaa*.txt")
    If Len(myFile) > 0 Then
        Name myPath & myFile As myPath & "hello.txt"
    End If

    'check for a bb file
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "bb*.txt")
    If Len(myFile) > 0 Then
        Name myPath & myFile As myPath & "bye.txt"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the macro but it just renames the first file (aaa *)

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood.  As I understand it now, you have two files in the folder, correct?  And, you want to rename them accordingly, correct?